# I can use two rewrite rules on my wordpress .htacces?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a multisite Wordpress, and i have a problem loading images.

if i put this code everything works great

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/$2 [L]
```

Only one of the two rules works.

What is the correct Syntax to use both?

Thanks!

Comment: What result were you expecting? How do you expect the rewrite engine to choose between these two identical match strings?

Comment: In mi wordpress multisite i have 7 sub sites. the first rule make 6 sites display images. But not the last one. The second rule, make display the images in the last site, but not in the others.... i don't know why.

Comment: No, you're still not getting it. The first RewriteRule will modify (i.e., rewrite) all the request URIs of the form `files/name_of_file` or `directory_name/files/name_of_file` into the form `wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=name_of_file`. So when the second rule is reached, there is nothing for it to do, because all the request URIs that match this pattern will already have been rewritten. As I said before, **how do you expect the rewrite engine to choose between these two identical match strings?**